# Getting intellisense error in VSCode, when setting a method of an Interface

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript-typings, jsdoc

In the following code, intellisense works fine

`test.d.ts`:

```
export interface ITest {
    foo: string;
    setFoo(foo: string): ITest;
}

export as namespace JSDoc;
```

`test.js`:

```
/** @typeof {import("./test")} JSDoc */

/**
 * @returns {JSDoc.ITest}
 */
function test() {
    return {
        foo: "",
        setFoo: function (foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
            return this;
        }
    };
}

exports.test = test;
```

But if I uncomment the `//this.foo = this.foo;` line I get the following warning on the returned object of the `test` function:

> Type 'typeof setFoo' is not assignable to type '(foo: string) =>
>   ITest'.   Property 'setFoo' is missing in type 'setFoo' but required
>   in type 'ITest'.ts(2322) test.d.ts(3, 5): 'setFoo' is declared here.
>   test.d.ts(3, 5): The expected type comes from property 'setFoo' which
>   is declared here on type 'ITest'

Here it is in image form too:

[image: Image Form]

Any idea why this is happening how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `bar` in `test.d.js`, which is typeof `ITest`, but in your `bar` function you Don't have it.

Try something like this and check:

```
function bar() {
    this.foo = this.foo;
    this.bar = this;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: So if I edit one of the properties I have to set all of them? Is there a fast way to do that with destructuring?

Comment: `interface` requires to overload all it's properties

Comment: Updated the question so that the example makes more sense now. If I create a setter (without `Object.defineProperty`) do I have to set all the properties of the interface in it?

Comment: Yes, `setFoo` is now kinda typeof `ITest`

Comment: So if I have to properties I have to set every one in each function that alters one of them? No other workaround? (tried changing interface to class and didn't do anything)

Comment: It looks like doing `var self = this;` and replacing `this` with `self` fixes the issue